# Office 2010 monitoring calendar events

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, ms-office, office-interop

Hey all I have the following code in VB.net that i translated from C# that I [found on the internet](http://adriandev.blogspot.com/2008/01/listening-to-calendar-events-with.html) for monitoring a outlook calendar events (Add, modify and delete).

The code is:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private Sub ThisAddIn(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        Dim monitor As New CalendarMonitor(Me.Application.ActiveExplorer())

        AddHandler monitor.AppointmentAdded, AddressOf monitor_AppointmentAdded
        AddHandler monitor.AppointmentModified, AddressOf monitor_AppointmentModified
        AddHandler monitor.AppointmentDeleting, AddressOf monitor_AppointmentDeleting
    End Sub
 ...etc etc...
End Class
```

=======================

```
Public Class CalendarMonitor
    Private _explorer As Explorer
    Private _folderPaths As List(Of String)
    Private _calendarFolders As List(Of MAPIFolder)
    Private _calendarItems As List(Of Items)
    Private _deletedItemsFolder As MAPIFolder

    Public Event AppointmentAdded As EventHandler(Of EventArgs(Of AppointmentItem))
    Public Event AppointmentModified As EventHandler(Of EventArgs(Of AppointmentItem))
    Public Event AppointmentDeleting As EventHandler(Of CancelEventArgs(Of AppointmentItem))

    Public Sub New(anExplorer As Explorer)
        _folderPaths = New List(Of String)()
        _calendarFolders = New List(Of MAPIFolder)()
        _calendarItems = New List(Of Items)()

        _explorer = anExplorer
        _explorer.BeforeFolderSwitch += New ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeFolderSwitchEventHandler(AddressOf Explorer_BeforeFolderSwitch)

        Dim session As [NameSpace] = _explorer.Session
        Try
            _deletedItemsFolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems)
            HookupDefaultCalendarEvents(session)
        Finally
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session)
            session = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub HookupDefaultCalendarEvents(aSession As [NameSpace])
        Dim folder As MAPIFolder = aSession.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
        If folder IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                HookupCalendarEvents(folder)
            Finally
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder)
                folder = Nothing
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Explorer_BeforeFolderSwitch(aNewFolder As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
        Dim folder As MAPIFolder = TryCast(aNewFolder, MAPIFolder)
        '
        ' Hookup events to any other Calendar folder opened.
        '
        If folder IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                If folder.DefaultItemType = OlItemType.olAppointmentItem Then
                    HookupCalendarEvents(folder)
                End If
            Finally
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder)
                folder = Nothing
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HookupCalendarEvents(aCalendarFolder As MAPIFolder)
        If aCalendarFolder.DefaultItemType <> OlItemType.olAppointmentItem Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The MAPIFolder must use " + "AppointmentItems as the default type.")
        End If

        If (_folderPaths.Contains(aCalendarFolder.FolderPath) = False) AndAlso (IsUsersCalendar(aCalendarFolder)) Then
            Dim items As Items = aCalendarFolder.Items

            _folderPaths.Add(aCalendarFolder.FolderPath)
            _calendarFolders.Add(aCalendarFolder)
            _calendarItems.Add(items)

            items.BeforeItemMove += New MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(AddressOf Calendar_BeforeItemMove)
            items.ItemChange += New ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(AddressOf CalendarItems_ItemChange)
            items.ItemAdd += New ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(AddressOf CalendarItems_ItemAdd)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalendarItems_ItemAdd(anItem As Object)
        Dim appointment As AppointmentItem = TryCast(anItem, AppointmentItem)
        If appointment IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                RaiseEvent AppointmentAdded(Me, New EventArgs(Of AppointmentItem)(appointment))
            Finally
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment)
                appointment = Nothing
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalendarItems_ItemChange(anItem As Object)
        Dim appointment As AppointmentItem = TryCast(anItem, AppointmentItem)
        If appointment IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                RaiseEvent AppointmentModified(Me, New EventArgs(Of AppointmentItem)(appointment))
            Finally
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment)
                appointment = Nothing
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Calendar_BeforeItemMove(anItem As Object, aMoveToFolder As MAPIFolder, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
        If (aMoveToFolder Is Nothing) OrElse (IsDeletedItemsFolder(aMoveToFolder)) Then
            Dim appointment As AppointmentItem = TryCast(anItem, AppointmentItem)

            If appointment IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    'If AppointmentDeleting IsNot Nothing Then
                    '
                    ' Listeners to the AppointmentDeleting event can cancel the move operation if moving
                    ' to the deleted items folder.
                    '
                    Dim args As New CancelEventArgs(Of AppointmentItem)(appointment)
                    RaiseEvent AppointmentDeleting(Me, args)

                    Cancel = args.Cancel
                    'End If
                Finally
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment)
                    appointment = Nothing
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function IsUsersCalendar(aFolder As MAPIFolder) As Boolean
        '
        ' This is based purely on my observations so far - a better way?
        '
        Return (aFolder.Store IsNot Nothing)
    End Function

    Private Function IsDeletedItemsFolder(aFolder As MAPIFolder) As Boolean
        Return (aFolder.EntryID = _deletedItemsFolder.EntryID)
    End Function
End Class
```

And I am currently hitting an error on line that has this code:

```
_explorer.BeforeFolderSwitch += New ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeFolderSwitchEventHandler(AddressOf Explorer_BeforeFolderSwitch)
```

The error is:

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Public member 'BeforeFolderSwitch' on type
>   'ExplorerClass' not found.

What do I need to do in order to get it working in VB.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to VB's event wireup format:

```
AddHandler _explorer.BeforeFolderSwitch, AddressOf Explorer_BeforeFolderSwitch
```

Note that the explicit delegate construction is unnecessary.

Comment: Now the same error is on the code line **items.BeforeItemMove += New MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(AddressOf Calendar_BeforeItemMove)** and taking you're example again i change it to **AddHandler items.itemBeforeItemMove, AddressOf Calendar_BeforeItemMove** but it has an error on that saying **'itemBeforeItemMove' is not an event of 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items'**

Comment: @StealthRT: I think you misnamed that event - it should be 'BeforeItemMove' (you added an 'item' just before it).